# Getting null value in fragment spinner

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am trying to use filter in Fragment and implementing the dialog fragment.
This is the class that I am using

> public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements
>   FilterDialogFragment.FilterListener,
>   PostAdapter2.OnPostSelectedListener{ detail code }

this the dialogfragment based class for spinner choosing options

> public class FilterDialogFragment extends DialogFragment

this method is called upon clicking the filter button, which pops up dialog for spinner options of the filter

Declared

```
private FilterDialogFragment mFilterDialog;
```

in onCreateView

```
mFilterDialog = new FilterDialogFragment();
```

Method to call

```
public void  onFilterClicked(){

       mFilterDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FilterDialogFragment.TAG);

    }
```

after this upon selecting the spinner option and clicking apply this method is called in which **mFilterListener** is **null**  which should not be the case

```
public interface FilterListener {

        void onFilter(Filters filters);

    }



  FilterListener mFilterListener;

public void onSearchClicked() {


        Log.d("Message", String.valueOf(mFilterListener));
        if (mFilterListener != null) {
            Log.d("Message", "New 55555");
            mFilterListener.onFilter(getFilters());
        }

        dismiss();
    }
```

please assist me to solve this problem. if anymore details are required please let me know

attach method in FilterDialogFragement

```
 public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        Log.d("Message", "New 6666666");
        Log.d("Message", String.valueOf(mFilterListener));

        if (context instanceof FilterListener) {

           // Log.d("Message", String.valueOf(mFilterListener));

            mFilterListener = (FilterListener) context;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried to shorten the code, please help me , I deleted the previous long detailed question

Comment: how do you set `mFilterListener`?

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin added the mFilterListener

Comment: but how do u pass it in `mFilterDialog`?

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin added above mFilterdialog

Comment: you did not show the initialisation of mFilterListener, only the declaration. In onCreateView, you create the dialog fragment, but do not pass in HomeFragment as a FilterListener instance.

Comment: @Mercato I was referring this example https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-android in this also it is the similar thing

Comment: does your FilterDialogFragment have the onAttach(Context context){} implementation as well? if not, that is why, and I'll make an answer saying why.

Comment: @Mercato added above, it might be wrong

Comment: got it. i know the reason. making an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to mimic this library implementation: [Friendly Eats](https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/example/fireeats/FilterDialogFragment.java).

However, you do not copy it wholesale, mainly in that you choose to use `HomeFragment` which `implements FilterDialogFragment.FilterListener` to launch `FilterDialogFragment`, rather than the library's `MainActivity`. This is the cause of your null pointer.

This is due to how `getSupportFragmentManager()` works. If you look at Android's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()) for this, you will see it says

> Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this **activity**. (My Bolding)

When you call `mFilterDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FilterDialogFragment.TAG);` inside `HomeFragment`, you are actually calling whatever `Activity` that is the parent of `HomeFragment` to launch the new `FilterDialogFragment`. You could double check this by checking if, in `onAttach(Context context)` inside `HomeFragment`, if `context instanceof HomeFragment`. I do not think it will return `true`.

To solve this, and without changing your use of `HomeFragment`, you could simply pass an instance of `HomeFragment` itself, or a separate implementation of `FilterDialogFragment.FilterListener` (which I'd prefer if you do not need to use anything from `HomeFragment` other than the listener) to your `FilterDialogFragment` instance on creation or before you launch it.

For example, you could create a public setter like so:

```
private FilterListener mFilterListener;

public void setFilterListener(FilterListener filterListener){
    mFilterListener = filterListener;
}
```

and then in your `HomeFragment onCreateView()`, you do this:

```
mFilterDialog = new FilterDialogFragment();

//Or preferably, an anonymous/named implementing instance of the interface only.
mFilterDialog.setFilterListener(this);
```

Doing so would not rely on the Android framework to provide the initialisation of your field, and does not require you to either change your `Activity` or `HomeFragment` you are currently using.

Comment: Thanks for this great knowledge, but when I am attempting to for setter 'setFilterListener' it is giving me error and asking to rename it to FilterDialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that u didnt set the listener in a `mFilterDialog`, so thats why its `null`

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: smth like, `mFilterDialog.mFilterListener = new FilterListener() { ... }`